# UICollectionView shows two line but I only want one line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I meet a strange mistake when I use UICollectionView, look at the pic below:

The third cell seems to be somehow show under the second, and the place for the third cell turns out to be empty.

[image]

When I scroll the view away and then back(or reload the view) , it turns to be right:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return datas.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
 }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellId = @"floorCell";
    FloorCollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dic = [datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.goodImageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"img"]];
    cell.goodLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];
    return cell;

}
```

And the Layout I use is UICollectionViewFlowLayout, the delegate for layout is as below:

```
#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize retval = CGSizeMake(172 / 2.0, [FloorCollectionViewCell getHeight]);
    return retval;
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

And I want to know the reason and how to solve the problem? thanks!

The code to init the collectionView:

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 278, bottomView.frame.size.height)  collectionViewLayout:layout];
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [collectionView registerClass:[FloorCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"floorCell"];
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    collectionView.delegate = self;
    [bottomView addSubview:collectionView];
```

ps: I think I have solved the problem by change the height of the collectionView to be just the height of the cell instead of the height of the whole gray superview. But I still don`t know the reason, the height of the gray superView is not big enough to hold two cells!

The code that changed :

```
collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 278, [FloorCollectionViewCell getHeight])  collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Comment: Please post the code from where you have initialized the collection(maybe in your viewdidload).

Comment: @Thapa I have attached the code

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's even a point in answering this anymore but for future's sake you could solve this problem just by setting a **height constraint** on to the **collection view itself** which would force the collection view to not get into multiline mode.This generally happens when you have set up Auto-Layout constraints with different priorities and there is more than enough space for collection view to expand.